# How to guarantee a specific set of characters as input to a string_view parameter?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, character, c++17, string-view

I'm working on a design implementation where I want the input to be selected from a specific set of characters for its string literal representation.

Consider the following set of classes:

```
class enum BaseType {
    BINARY = 2,
    OCTAL = 8,
    DECIMAL = 10,
    HEXADECIMAL = 16
};

template<BaseType BASE = BaseType::DECIMAL> // Default Template
class Foo {
public:
    const uint16_t Base{BASE};
private: 
    std::string digits_;
    int64_t integral_value_;
    int64_t decimal_value_;
    size_t decimal_index_location_;
public:
    Foo() 
      : digits_{""}, 
        integral_value_{0}, 
        decimal_value_{0}
        decimal_index_location_{0}
    {}
    Foo(const std::string_view digit_sequence) 
      : digits_{digit_sequence}, 
        integral_value_{0}, 
        decimal_value_{0}
        decimal_index_location{0}
    {
        // set values according to the respective digits 
        // from the decimal point if one exists
        // and set the decimal index location if one exists...
    }
};
```

---

I may have to use specializations for the other non-default types which have yet to be decided. Regardless of that, I want to restrict each case to the following character set as follows:

- `BINARY` :
  `'0'`, `'1'`, `'.'`
- `OCTAL` :
  `['0' - '7']`, `'.'`
- `DECIMAL` :
  `['0' - '9']`, `'.'`
- `HEXADECIMAL` :
  `['0' - '9']`, `['a' - 'f']`, `['A' - 'F']`, `'.'`

---

These would be acceptable inputs for each type:

- `BINARY` :

  - `"010"`, `".010"`, `"01.0"`, `"01.`" etc...
- `OCTAL` :

  - `"012345670"`, `".012345670"`, `"01.2345670"`, `"1."`, etc...
- `DECIMAL` :

  - `"01234567890"`, `".01234567890"`, `"01.234567890"`, `"1."`, etc...
- `HEXADECIMAL` :

  - `"0123456789abcdef0"`, `".0123456789abcdef0"`, `"01.23456789abcdef0"`, `"1."`, etc...
  - `"0123456789ABCDEF0"`, `".0123456789ABCDEF0"`, `"01.23456789ABCDEF0"`, `"1."`, etc...

To be the only valid set of input characters for the `string_view` parameter of the class's constructor.

---

Is there a simple, elegant, and efficient way of doing this? If so, how? It doesn't really matter if this is handled by throwing exceptions, compile-time or run-time assertions... I just want to limit the possible set of valid characters for each templated version...

---

**EDIT**

For each of the cases even a single `'.'` is valid input. For example:

```
Foo a(".");
```

Would be interpreted as `0` and later when I incorporate the `exponent` part, the exponent would evaluate to `1` so that the result would be `0` and not `1` due to power rules...

Comment: Use a regex to see if the input matches the correct pattern?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'll have to look into it, I've never really worked with `regex` that much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), you might do:

```
static const std::regex binary_regex(R"([01]*\.?[01]*)");
static const std::regex octal_regex(R"([0-7]*\.?[0-7]*)");
static const std::regex decimal_regex(R"([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)");
static const std::regex hex_regex(R"([0-9a-fA-F]*\.?[0-9a-fA-F]*)");

bool do_match(const std::string& s, const std::regex& regex)
{
    // if (s.empty()) { return false; }
    std::smatch base_match;
    
    return std::regex_match(s, base_match, regex);   
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/700adc90cde809c7)

You might even with grouping get the value before dot and after dot

Comment: I like the advice, just a simple question for clarity... Will the above allow for only a single `.`? I don't want a string such as `243.4252.342`.

Comment: yes only one dot is allowed so only numbers of the forms "", "00", "00.", "00.00", ".00" are allowed.

Comment: There is only one issue with this... everything works fine so far, but when I pass in a string such as `"24526"` without a decimal point, `regex` is throwing an unhandled exception...

Comment: [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/700adc90cde809c7) added, and no issues here.

Comment: Well, I turned your `do_match` into a `static const auto lambda` outside of the `class template` and gave it the name `match`.  I have also created a `static const map<BaseType,std::regex>` and populated it with the 4 variants. Then I'm using this `match lambda` within `assert` inside of the constructor... and I'm using the `map`'s `at()` function using the `BASE` as its `key` to select the appropriate `regex` type. It's failing for me when there are no `.` within the `string_view`.... I'm also using `Visual Studio 2017` in `C++17` or `latest draft standard` mode...

Comment: Can you provide link from coliru or godbolt (or other) (or ask another question).

Comment: I'm still working on it and within my own IDE atm... I've made a few changes and stuff so I'll get back to testing that again...

Comment: It will compile and build just fine, but it immediately crashes when running. https://godbolt.org/z/9Tds89

Comment: It's also crashing before the call to the first instantiation of the class template's constructor...

Comment: You got some typos: `)` instead of `]` and extra `*`, fixed version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f98bfaecc820e31a) (I also fixed code unrelated to regex).

Comment: Simplified version using group in regex [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cecb1bdd98988440). Notice though that way you count decimal is probably not what you expect for non decimal: `0.1` in binary is `0.25`, and even in decimal leading `0` are lost 0.9 .

Comment: I finally got a chance to come back to this project and work with it again. I check out your demo and compared it to what I already had. After seeing what you had done with `std::cmatch` is starting to make sense... I'm new to the `std::regex` part of the `stl`.  Also, after fixing some of the `typos` within the predefined regular expressions, everything is now working as from your demo or your example. With that, I'll go ahead and except your answer!